# Why does not composer create behat.yml file?

Tags: php, magento, composer-php, behat

I want use behat for my Magento shop.

I installed BehatMage with this [documentation](https://github.com/MageTest/BehatMage).

But when I come to "Basic Usage" and want execute following command, it does not create `behat.yml` in project folder.

```
$ cd project
$ bin/behat --init
```

I thought after running:

```
composer install --dev --prefer-dist
```

with this configuration:

```
{
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "magetest/magento-behat-extension": "dev-develop"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "html/app",
                "html/app/code/local",
                "html/app/code/community",
                "html/app/code/core",
                "html/lib"
            ]
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

... this file should be created or at least filled with informations?
The `composer install` command worked well without any errors.

Any ideas how I create a configured behat.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add behat to `require-dev` (not sure about version, 2.5 is just a guess):

```
"require-dev": {
    "behat/behat": "~2.5",
    "magetest/magento-behat-extension": "dev-develop"
},
```

The documentation you are referring to clearly says:

> For this document we assume the directory layout is as follows.

with behat already installed, and then

> First, **add** BehatMage to the list of dependencies

with a snippet of composer **to be added** to your composer.json.

It will install executable `bin/behat`.

You need to create your own `behat.yml`, which is relevant to your application.
An example of the file with `BehatMage` enabled is provided as [behat.yml.dist](https://github.com/MageTest/BehatMage/blob/develop/behat.yml.dist)

Comment: Okay - I found several other tutorials and got some configurations for behat.yml. Now I run into [database connection problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573676/why-can-magento-behat-test-not-find-my-database), but this is good for another question.